# Problems involving multiline Arabic lemmata in critical apparatus (Reledmac)

Tags: xetex, reledmac

Line numbers involving multiline lemmata will not display properly in Arabic. (For comparison, I have included an English passage with a multiline lemma. No problem there.) In this minimal working example, the line number of the first Arabic lemma displays correctly as '1', but line numbers of the second lemma show up as '0' where they should be '2-4'. (Note: While compiling, I get the error message '! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.'.)

```
    % !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
    % !TEX TS-program = xelatex

    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}

    \Xbeforeinserting[A]{\LTR} % I took these commands from the example 2-reledmac-right-to-left.tex, where they edited a Hebrew text.
    \Xlemmaseparator[A]{[} % Will be reversed by Arabic font
    \Xafterlemmaseparator[A]{0.5em}
    \Xbeforelemmaseparator[A]{0.25em}
    \Xwrapcontent[A]{\textenglish}
    \Xwraplemma[A]{\RL}

    %polyglossia packages - polyglossia must be first
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \usepackage{bidi}

    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{arabic}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

    \title{Minimal Working Example}
    \author{Emre Coşkun}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{Arabic}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    \edtext{كتبه وشكّله وصحّحه}{\Afootnote{om. \textbf{A}}}

    \edtext{كتبه وشكّله وصحّحه مقابلة وحلّاً الفقير إلى الله تعالى محمّد بن عمر بن أحمد بن أبي جرادة. وفرغ منه في الثاني من ذي الحجّة سنة أربع وثمانين وستّمائة حامداً لله تعالى ومصلّياً على سيّدنا محمّد وعلى آله وصحبه ومسلّماً.}{\Afootnote{om. \textbf{A}}}
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{Arabic}

    \section{New Section}
    \begin{english}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    \edtext{We've all heard that a million monkeys banging on a million typewriters will eventually reproduce the entire works of Shakespeare. Now, thanks to the Internet, we know that is not true. (Robert Wilensky)}{\Bfootnote{om. \textbf{B}}}
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{english}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I think there is a bug in reledmac. I will look on it this afternoon.

Comment: that is indeed a bug of reledmac. I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 2.18.0 of reledmac, just send on CTAN, solve this bug with long edtext in Right-to-Left mode.